# Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'FashionWorldApp.Domain.Abstract.IOrderProcessor' is less accessible than field '

Tags: c#

From the Code below, i kept having this error inconsistent accessibility with reference to  private IOrderProcessor orderProcessor;. I have changed the private to public but the error still persists. Can some one help me out?

```
namespace FashionWorldApp.WebUI.Controllers
{
public class CartController : Controller    {
    private IProductRepository repository;
    private IOrderProcessor orderProcessor;

    public CartController(IProductRepository repo, IOrderProcessor proc)
    {
        repository = repo;
        orderProcessor = proc;
    }

    public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new CartIndexViewModel
        {
            Cart = cart,
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    public PartialViewResult Summary(Cart cart)
    {
        return PartialView(cart);
    }

    [HttpPost]
 public ViewResult Checkout(Cart cart, ShippingDetails  shippingDetails)
    {
        if (cart.Lines.Count() == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry, your cart is empty!");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            orderProcessor.ProcessOrder(cart, shippingDetails);
            cart.Clear();
            return View("Completed");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(shippingDetails);
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Checkout()
    {
        return View(new ShippingDetails());
    }
     public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart
          (Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

        if (product != null)
        {
            cart.AddItem(product, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }

 public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart
         (Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.Products
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

        if (product != null)
        {
            cart.RemoveLine(product);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your definition of IOrderProcessor. My hunch is that it's not a public interface. Also what is the full error?

Answer (score 0):

Change IProductRepository interface to public. You have a public constructor which accepts IProductRepository as parameter, you need to guarantee outside invokes can see it.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding. it has been handled.

Comment: But still, can some one help with the steps to create a directory to store email files from an application